# Slow query on ecommerce website (selecting products)

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

```
SELECT products.* 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN product_category 
    ON products.id_product = product_category.id_produs 
LEFT JOIN categories 
    ON product_category.id_category = categories.id_category
INNER JOIN options 
    ON products.id_product = options.id_product 
WHERE categories.id_category = '472' 
AND product_category.id_category = categories.id_category
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Hello, I'm working on a ecommerce website for a programming contest and I have some issues with the category page, where the products will be listed.

In MySQL there are 4 tables: products, categories, product_category (which contains the relation of category and products) and options. The options table contains various attributes for a product that you can choose to buy (like weight, height, color). I need to call these on the category page because there is a product filter, and when I chose color: red, it will show all the products with the attribute color: red.

If I have 10 000 rows in products table, and each product have 5 options, so the options table will have 50 000 rows, the problem is that the query will be very slow, and it will take more than 30 seconds to display the products.
I'm sure the problem is with the query, but I don't how to make it. What should I write in the query in order to get the products on the page in under 5 seconds?

Comment: can you include the execution plan for this query?

Comment: Are there indizes on your id_category/id_product columns?

Comment: Post the [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) of your query

Comment: "I need to call these on the category page because there is a product filter, and when I chose color: red, it will show all the products with the attribute color: red". Are you always joining to options, even if the filter is not applied? If so you'd be getting "duplicate" products, since they're multiplied by all options and option values. And it would take more time of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have indexes on id_category and id_product for those tables, then stick `EXPLAIN` in front of it, and post the output, to be honest, if you don't have indexes, that might do the job anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Indexes was the problem as they were not defined.

Comment: Glad it helped. Make sure you accept answers on this site – otherwise people won't answer more of your questions! :)

Answer (score 0):

A few things: You're specifying this relationship twice:

```
AND product_category.id_category = categories.id_category
```

and

```
ON product_category.id_category = categories.id_category
```

This may be confusing your database optimizer.

Another potential optimization is to move the column you are doing your WHERE clause on up a table. Turn `WHERE categories.id_category = '472'` into `product_category.id_category = '472'`
` and it will reduce the number of records being joined in.

As mentioned in some of the questions, an `EXPLAIN` plan will show you what part of your query is slow, and give you an indication if there are indexes missing.